# How can you add a link to a google site via a Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have been scripting a few ways to make my Google site easier to manage by dynamically creating pages. I want to be able to create a directory with links to those pages.

So i was thinking something like...

```
var page = site.getChildByName("NEW URL");
var link = [page.getUrl()];
page = site.getChildByName("URL TO DIRECTORY").addListItem(link);
```

...using google apps scripts. Haven't tested this too thoroughly as of yet but it haven't been able to get the links to work in the list. I was hoping to just keep the page template as a normal webpage.

If I went that route would editing the html be the only option? Hopefully there is an easier way.

Any ideas would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I added a scrollpanel to handle the variable height of the list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a small test that shows a list of all the pages in your site

```
function doGet() {
  var app=UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Directory of this site")
  var mainPanel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setStyleAttributes({background:'beige',padding:'20px'});
  var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(450,300);
  var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl('https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/')
  var pages = site.getAllDescendants()
  var grid = app.createGrid(pages.length,2).setWidth(400)
    for(n=0;n<pages.length;++n){
    grid.setText(n, 0, pages[n].getName()).setWidget(n, 1, app.createAnchor('open', pages[n].getUrl()))
    }
    app.add(mainPanel.add(scroll.add(grid)))
    return app
}
```

I suppose you know ho to use it in your sitepage but just for info for anyone else : you have to go to *manage site > script apps > create a new script > save a version > deploy* **with appropriate authorizations** and finally return to your page and insert it as a gadget (better with a border and a size of 450x300, personal pov ^^) . You can also use it as a standalone webapp using its deploy url.

[image]

Comment: ahhhh okay so I can just mod this to get the descendants of my dir page. The only thing that worries me is that I am running the page build script in junction with another ui instance so I will have to separate this script to just keep the "grid" update with new pages as they come in. 

Thank you!! This is going to be a huge help!

Comment: You could as well integrate this snippet in another script as far as the `getAllDescendants` statement comes after any new page is created. Well, I didn't test it in that context but it seems pretty logical (is what we are doing logical ? ^^)

Comment: So I have ran into a bit of a problem with the scrolling functionality.

Comment: When I replace the `var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl ` with `var site = SitesApp.getPageByUrl ` in order to make this a directory of just a subpage of my total site. I lose the Scrolling functionality of ScrollPanel.

Comment: Are you sure there are enough rows in the list to have something to scroll through?  (I know this is a silly question but who knows? :-)  I'll test on my side and see what happens.

Comment: I just tested and, as I suspected, it works exactly the same way... I guess something else must have change on your side. please open a new question if necessary showing your code.

Comment: Will do. You may be right because the list is significantly shorter, I will play with the dimensions and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: If I make the dimensions of the scroll panel smaller than the list it should invoke the scrolling functionality correct?

Comment: Yes, that's how I made the test too :-)

Comment: Not sure what the deal was but it works now. Had to adjust the Ui instance window height I think.. 
Thanks again for this it was a huge help!